# I have google analytics code in my wordpress site and google says it can read the data but no data is being passed , 

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I was using a plug-in called analyticator and also had the code pasted in by accident so i took out the extra code and now i still have no data for analytics. If someone could intervene and provide some insight I would appreciate it. My website is at www.knowledgenation.us .

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question. Your site doesn't have any google analytics on it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) extension for Google Chrome is excellent for debugging these kinds of problems.

It will show, in the developer console of Chrome, exactly what analytics calls are triggered by a particular page.

[image: An example of the Analytics Debugger output]